# Clarification on notation in Siegfried Bosch's Commutative Algebra book about primary decomposition of ideals.

Tags: commutative-algebra, notation, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm reading through Siegfried Bosch's Commutative Algebra book, and I'm confused on his notation in one his proofs. He uses this notation a lot, so I think I should I understand it. The notation first appears in his proof of Theorem 8:

**Theorem 8.** For a decomposable ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subset R$, let $\mathfrak{a} = \bigcap_{i=1}^r \mathfrak{q_i}$ be a minimal primary decomposition. Then the set of corresponding prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i = \text{rad}(\mathfrak{q}_i)$ coincides with the set of all prime ideals in $R$ that are of type $\text{rad}\big((\mathfrak{q}:x)\big)$ for $x$ varying over $R$.

In his proof, he writes: Let $x\in R$. The primary decomposition of $\mathfrak{a}$ yields $(\mathfrak{a}:x) = \bigcap_{i=1}^r(\mathfrak{q_i}:x)$ and therefore by Lemma 7, a primary decomposition

$
\text{rad}\big((\mathfrak{a}:x)\big) = \bigcap_{i=1}^r\text{rad}\big((\mathfrak{q}_i:x)\big) = \bigcap_{x\not\in \mathfrak{q}_i}\mathfrak{p}_i.
$

What I'm confused about is that last equality, what's that mean? The indexing confuses me. If it's helpful, here's the part of Lemma 7 I think he's using.

**Lemma 7.**  Consider a primary ideal $\mathfrak{q}\subset R$ and the corresponding prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} = \text{rad}(\mathfrak{q})$. Then, for $x\not\in \mathfrak{q}$, $(\mathfrak{q}:x)$ is $\mathfrak{p}$-primary.

Thank you.

Comment: Which indexing, the last bit? Does writing it as $\bigcap_{i \in I} \mathfrak{p}_i$ where $I = \{i \in \{1, \dots, r\} | x \notin \mathfrak{q}_i\}$ or something help?

Comment: Yes, the last bit. Is that what he means?

Comment: Looking at it, yeah, that's what he means. I knew it was something simple like that.

Comment: Thank you. This question's quite silly now. Should I delete it?